# to.be.revertedWith("Error Message ") returning failed test despite custom error matching "Error Message"

Tags: unittesting, waffle, revert

I'm running tests on a raffle smart contract from Patrick Collin's tutorial. I have custom errors in my Solidity file.

When running tests that expect the transaction to be reverted, every single time I get an error like this:

```
1) Raffle
       enterRaffle
         doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating:
     AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'Raffle__NotOpen', but it reverted with a custom error
```

I've triple checked that the text of the custom error is identical to the value I've pasted into to.be.revertedWith("). This happens for every single test I write which uses revertedWith(). When I use reverted or revertedWithCustomError, the tests pass without issue.

Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You're reverting with a revert reason string rather than a [custom error](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/).

Comment: Btw, it might help if you took a look at my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

Answer (score 2):

I think `revertedWith` looks for a **string message** as we can see here on hardhat documentation

[image]

And... the `revertedWithCustomError`, for a **custom error**.
So this behavior is correct IMO, since you're using **Raffle__NotOpen** and it is a *custom error*.

[image]

In another use case, I had a similar problem using `revertedWithCustomError`, btw I was using `onlyOwner` and it was raising an error before with a **string error**, not my custom one.

I'm on the same course, but using **hardhat**.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the course though, Patrick is able to get the tests to pass with this exact syntax, so I'm perplexed why it's erroring out on me.

Comment: maybe they updated the lib and then is not accepting like was for Patrick before haha